# Nginx site cannot be accessed through domain URL

Tags: django, http, nginx, server, dns

**The problem:**

I have set up a (Docker) Django-Gunicorn-Nginx site on my home network. It works on the local network but I cannot access it through my domain.

**The setup:**

- Registered a domain in namecheap.com.
- Set up a dynamic DNS to update my public IP with the namecheap domain.
- Set up the website on a computer in my home network and give it a static IP.
- Enable port forwarding from public 80 to LAN 80.

**The tests:**

- I have enabled port forwarding on the port 22 and I have been able to connect through SSH to the computer serving the website with `ssh user@domain`  and it worked well -> `domain/ddns ok`.
- I have accessed to the website from another computer connected on the same LAN by using the full static IP to the computer serving the website and it worked well -> `website/server ok`.
- I have called my ISP to check if everything is set up correctly and if I am allowed to serve a website form my network and apparently there are no issues -> `router/network ok`.

**The clue:**

When I try to access the site from outside my home network, through the domain or my full public IP, I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

When I try to access the site from my home network, through the domain or with the full public IP (not through the LAN IP which actually works), I get redirected to the page 192.168.0.1/intercept.html which contains a message from my ISP saying that I do not have connection to the internet (which I actually have):

[image]

So, at this point I am a bit lost. I'd like to get ideas on what is the best way to troubleshot this situation.

Comment: More often than not ISPs block port 80. The ‘ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE’ appears to suggest port forwarding is not setup correctly or not working as expected. Maybe try a diff port like 8080 and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ben5556 suggested, I tried port 8000 and it worked :) So my ISP is probably blocking port 80.

First I tried port 8080 but while enabling the port forwarding on the router configuration page, it showed a warning stating that this port is reserved for other stuff so I tried with port 8000 instead.

This is annoying since I called my ISP and they said that there should be no problem in using port 80. Moreover, there is no warning at all when enabling port forwarding on port 80.

**UPDATE**

Serving the web on public port 8000 makes no sense since browsers default to port 80, so the final solution has been to enable port forwarding from public 80 to LAN 8000. Apparently only LAN port 80 is blocked so this solution works nicely.

Comment: Do not trust your ISP, they are evil people that only want your money.